# Dynamic element appending inside another another 2 dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a three dynamic element. In this am appending one dynamic element into other 2 dynamic elements. What the problem occur is it removes from the first element and then appends to next element.

```
var a = $('<div>');
var b = $('<div>');


var c = $('<a>');
c.text('apple');
a.addClass('a');
b.addClass('b');

b.append(c);
a.append(c);

$('.i1').append(a);
$('.i2').append(b);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5zm5ffp/3/

Comment: In your jsfiddle what is i1 and i2? Since those are missing the code won't run as expected.

Comment: Fiddle updated. i1 and i2 are just the static element in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new object before appending it, for example by calling `$.clone` method:

```
b.append(c.clone());
a.append(c.clone());

$('.i1').append(a);
$('.i2').append(b);
```

Comment: Its working!!!..Thank you so much. May I know the reason of why it is not working for append.

Comment: I believe that `append` just moves the DOM element to some new place, so when you call it twice with the same DOM element (`c`), you are basically moving the element from "position 1" to "position 2", and right after that to "position 3".

Comment: @johnie To put it in a way, what your code did was move the element `c` from one `div` to another. That's whay you had to clone it to append the element the way you wanted it.